# Extracting anchor text from span class with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrape

This is the html I am trying to scrape:

```
<span class="meta-attributes__attr-tags">
<a href="/tags/cinematic" title="cinematic">cinematic</a>, 
<a href="/tags/dissolve" title="dissolve">dissolve</a>,
<a href="/tags/epic" title="epic">epic</a>,
<a href="/tags/fly" title="fly">fly</a>,
</span>
```

I want to get the anchor text for each a href: cinematic, dissolve, epic, etc.

This is the code I have:

```
url = urllib2.urlopen("http: example.com")

content = url.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

links = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "meta-attributes__attr-tags"})
for link in links:
    print link.find_all('a')['href']
```

If I do it with "link.find_all" I get error: TypeError: List indices must be integers, not str.

But if I do print link.find('a')['href'] I get the first one only.

How can I get all of them ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content = '''
<span class="meta-attributes__attr-tags">
<a href="/tags/cinematic" title="cinematic">cinematic</a>, 
<a href="/tags/dissolve" title="dissolve">dissolve</a>,
<a href="/tags/epic" title="epic">epic</a>,
<a href="/tags/fly" title="fly">fly</a>,
</span>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
spans = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "meta-attributes__attr-tags"})
for span in spans:
    links = span.find_all('a')
    for link in links:
        print link['href']
```

**Output**

```
/tags/cinematic
/tags/dissolve
/tags/epic
/tags/fly
```

Comment: Yeah this would work, but I am trying to do it on a webpage which has a ton of <a hrefs>. I am looking to scrape particularly in that span class, the a hrefs.

Comment: @AlexTheWebGroup I've updated my answer - should be exactly what you want now.

Comment: It is a bit pricey to search for links in the `span` with `soup.find_all('a')`. Why not search only the `span` element itself?

Comment: @dm295 - agreed, typo!

Comment: Yeah this works, but how do I get the actual text from the <a> </a> tags? I remember it was something with .contents but don't know exactly.

Comment: Add `print link.text` inside the `for` loop

Answer (score 3):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<span class="meta-attributes__attr-tags">
<a href="/tags/cinematic" title="cinematic">cinematic</a>, 
<a href="/tags/dissolve" title="dissolve">dissolve</a>,
<a href="/tags/epic" title="epic">epic</a>,
<a href="/tags/fly" title="fly">fly</a>,
</span>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
spans = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "meta-attributes__attr-tags"})

for span in spans:
    for link in span.find_all('a'):
        print link.text, link['href']
```

Another, pricier, way could be:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<span class="meta-attributes__attr-tags">
<a href="/tags/cinematic" title="cinematic">cinematic</a>,
<a href="/tags/dissolve" title="dissolve">dissolve</a>,
<a href="/tags/epic" title="epic">epic</a>,
<a href="/tags/fly" title="fly">fly</a>,
</span>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
links = soup.find_all("a")

for link in links:
    if 'meta-attributes__attr-tags' not in link.parent.get('class', []):
        continue

    print link.text, link['href']
```

Answer (score 2):

`link.find_all('a')` returns a list with bs4 Tags. You probably want to index each of this links by `href`. So maybe this comes closer to your needs:

```
span = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "meta-attributes__attr-tags"})
for links in span:
    for link in links.find_all('a'):
        print(link['href'])
```

Comment: Yeah this works, but how do I get the actual text from the <a> </a> tags? I remember it was something with .contents but don't know exactly.

Comment: Use `link.getText()` instead of `link['href']` if you want to get the content. Or if it can contain child elements, `link.contents` gives a list of the contents.

Answer (score 1):

You may avoid nested loops or any additional if checks inside a loop by using a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
for link in soup.select(".meta-attributes__attr-tags a[href]"):
    print(link["href"], link.get_text())
```